# Error when uploading file in IE11 with DSpace 4.0

Tags: dspace

Error when uploading file in IE11 with DSpace 4.0

this appears when uploading file when submitting a new item. It works fine in Chrome.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could expand the Java stacktrace / Java full stacktrace sections on the error page. Perhaps put them somewhere like pastebin and add a link to your question.

Comment: Hi! Thanks! You can find the Java stacktrace and Java full stacktrace here: http://www.filedropper.com/javastacktracejavafullstacktrace

Comment: could someone please help me?

Comment: Your stacktrace link doesn't work :(

Comment: It works for me. You need to click the "Download this file" button.

Comment: You're right, sorry -- the page looked so dodgy that I didn't even look around for a download button. Next time perhaps use something like pastebin or gist, to make it easy for people to look at the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you that it can't create a file:

```
java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
  at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
  at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:947)
  at edu.sdsc.grid.io.local.LocalFile.createNewFile(LocalFile.java:486)
```

I don't know why you'd get that with one browser but not another, but you should double check file system permissions and what you've set up as the asset store location ([DSpace 4 config location](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-4_x/dspace/config/dspace.cfg#L150)).

Also check the directories that Tomcat is using to temporarily store files, which will depend on your server's operating system, Tomcat version, etc. Check that all these directories exist and that the user that Tomcat runs under has permissions to create files and subdirectories.

Comment: This is my asset store in dspace.cfg: assetstore.dir = ${dspace.dir}/assetstore - is it OK?

Comment: directory "assetstore" has the following rights rwsrwxrwt, owner: dspace

Comment: the directories in directory assetstore has rights: rwxr-xr-x, owner differs between dspace, root and tomcat7 for different directories

Comment: could someone help me please?